# Cannot post to EntitySetController, the received entity is null

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, odata, complextype

I'm trying to post data to `EntitySetController`, but the entity which is received by the controller is always `null`.

The `OData` config is:

```
public static class ODataApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                config.Routes.MapODataRoute("DefaultOdata" , "odata" , GetImplicitModel());
            }

        public static IEdmModel GetImplicitModel()
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<ZipCode>("ZipCodes");        

            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
```

I have the following controller:

```
public class ZipCodesController : EntitySetController<ZipCode, String>
    {
         public IUnitOfWork Iuow { get; set; }

         public ZipCodesController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
         {
             Iuow = unitOfWork;
         }

         [Queryable]
         public override IQueryable<ZipCode> Get()
         {
             return Iuow.GetStandardRepository<ZipCode>().GetAll();
         }

         protected override string GetKey(ZipCode entity)
         {
             return entity.Id.ToString();
         }
         protected override ZipCode GetEntityByKey(string key)
         {
             return Iuow.GetStandardRepository<ZipCode>().GetById(key);
         }

         protected override ZipCode CreateEntity(ZipCode entity)
         {
             Iuow.GetStandardRepository<ZipCode>().Add(entity);
             Iuow.Commit();
             return entity;
         }
    }
```

The ZipCode is defined as so:

```
 public class ZipCode
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public long Version { get; set; }
            public String CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public String LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
            public String ZipPostalCode{ get; set; }
            public ZipCodeType ZipCodeType { get; set; }
            public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
            public Guid CountyId { get; set; }
            public Guid StateId { get; set; }
            public Guid CityId { get; set; }
            public String Latitude { get; set; }
            public String Longitude { get; set; }

        }
```

I'm trying to post the following entity through `Fiddler`, But the received entity is always `null`.

```
{"Id":"6b146d72-2681-4d47-8cc4-75e64e2dea66", "Version":20, "CreatedBy":"ae5882fb-b833-46d7-9f58-0505ec2a6f8f","LastModifiedBy":"ae5882fb-b833-46d7-9f58-0505ec2a6f8f","ZipPostalCode":"92020","ZipCodeType": 3,"CountryId":"6a54b9be-8726-4376-a99e-989884e2b724","CountyId":"9c4052fa-49f2-4e5e-995f-317abd16814b","StateId":"0da54905-6acd-4886-a9d1-f3e6d9eb7c60","CityId":"ba543bc1-7eb7-4e14-bbea-2ffcac5b2e2c","Latitude":"36.978256","Longitude":"-121.952464"}
```

I noticed that if I use the quotation marks for `version` and `ZipCodeType` fields (all non quotation fields) as `"Version":"20"` and `"ZipCodeType":"3"`, everything is fine and received entity is `not null`.

Please, help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Make sure you have `Content-Type' header for your request.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are not natively supported in OData V3. So, web API OData models them as strings instead. That is why you need to follow the string syntax i.e quoted.

Also, it always helps to check the model state for errors if an incoming parameter is null. More in this blog [post](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-and-handling-modelstate-validation). The sample code below helps,

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
}
```